# How do I use matplotlib to plot a single scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a single scatterplot for my online course using matplotlib, but sometimes multiple plots are showing up on the screen.

Here is the code:

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x[:2], y[:2], s=100, c='red', label='Tall students')
plt.scatter(x[2:], y[2:], s=100, c='blue', label='Short students')
plt.show()
```

My problem is that if I run the code twice I get two images like this:
[image]

If I run it again, I get only a single plot.

Is there any way to make sure I get only 1 plot here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.clf()` will clear the current figure.  `plt.cla()` will clear all subplots.